# StartActivityForResoult on ListViewItem click Android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, listadapter

I have an activity lets call it **Activity 1** and there we will have a ListView composed by Player objetcs. When you click on a ListView_item (on a Player) a new activity starts, lets call it **Activity 2**. What I want is:

Activity 1 sends to Activity 2 player's name and player's race. In Activity 2 the user could edit that (player's name and player's race) and when the user click on Confirm Ativity 2 sends to Activity 1 the player's name and player's race even I the user has not edited it (in that case it would send the previus that Activity 1 has sended to Activity 2).

The problem is that when I'm suposse to use startActivityForResult I'm into ListViewAdapter class and using context.start... startActivityForResult doesn't appears.

```
public class AdaptadorJugadores extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private ArrayList<Jugador> list = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
private Context context;


public AdaptadorJugadores(ArrayList<Jugador> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    return list.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return 0;
    //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista_jugadores, null);
    }

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView TextoNombreJugador = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.etNombreJugador);
    TextoNombreJugador.setText(list.get(position).getNombre());
    if (list.get(position).getGenero() == "Hombre"){
        TextoNombreJugador.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_face_black_24dp, 0, 0, 0);
    }else{
        TextoNombreJugador.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_face_black_girl24dp, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btEliminarJugador);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
            list.remove(position); //or some other task
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    /*addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });*/
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, VistaJugador.class);
            intent.putExtra("Nombre",(list.get(position).getNombre()));
            intent.putExtra("Genero",(list.get(position)).getGenero());
            // Start SingleItemView Class

        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: you can do it by casting with Activity but you wont get onActivityResult() inside adapter, so better user approach of @Francesc's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ListView's setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener) method and in there you could start the activity using startActivityForResult.

```
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // get the data to pass to the activity based on the position clicked
            Intent intent = new Intent(...);
            intent.setExtra(...);
            startActivityForResult(...);
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, you could pass the Activity to your adapter and use that instead of a context, but the first solution is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to pass the context from the Activity to the Adapter, then store it in a local variable. After that, you can just use it to startActivityForResult, but note that you have to implement the onActivityResultMethod. My suggestion is that you use an interface, then pass the ID of the selected item and call the startActivityForResult() in the Activity.

Comment: The activity context (the activity that contains listview) is stored into "context"